# WIX Installed property

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm doing an installer, using wix v3. I have two installers. I installed my app with the first one and then I want to update it with the second installer.

I think that I'm missing something since I cannot install the product and then run an update (with other installer), If I execute the same version, I could see the maintenance windows, it recognize that the product is installed. The problem is with other versions.

I think that these could be because of the value of the Installed property. What thing should I do to have these property set correctly? I'm installing the product for all users...

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your WIX project to be able to detect it's an Upgrade ?
Have a look at the [upgrade part](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson4.php) of the basic [WIX Tutorials](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/)